# Troops walking out on me

Tags: clash-of-clans

After I train troops, I see them hanging around the camp for a while, but then they start walking to the bottom part of the map and basically walk out of the map and into the beach, then they vanish.. and I never ever see them again... :'( 
What's going on?

Comment: I think what's happening is you are seeing troops being donated!  This is a normal visual response to you donating troops to other people in your clan.

Comment: @Jcraft153 Also if your in the war map and donate troops then you won't see them leave until you enter your village.

Answer (score 9):

This happens when you donate troops.